# How do I calculate CRC32 mathematically?

Tags: algorithm-design, crc

I want to calcuate the [CRC32 algorithm](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-CRCAppendix.html) using polynomials directly but I don't know how. I found the generating polynomial listed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check. This corresponds to `0xedb88320` in the example code.

Can someone please define a mathematical specification that calculates the same result as this algorithm?

Comment: Did you read this link, it seems to be just what you are looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_CRC.

Comment: @Thomas, yes but this does not help, thank you though.

Comment: Does ["A Painless Guide to CRC Error Detection Algorithms"](http://www.ross.net/crc/) help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a non-cryptographic checksum function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common CRC32 is borrowed from the 32-bit Frame Check Sequence in the 1988 edition of CCITT V.42, section 8.1.1.6.2, available [here](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.42-198811-S/en), which gives a mathematical definition (note: remove the obviously spurious $1$ after $x^{30}$ in the English edition).

I prefer this alternate definition with some of the math on polynomial replaced by equivalent operations on bits:

1. Consider the message as a sequence of $n$ bits in chronological order (if the message is structured in words or bytes: with low-order bit first unless otherwise specified).
2. Append $32$ *one* bits, forming a sequence of $n+32$ bits.
3. Complement the first $32$ bits of that sequence.
4. Form the binary polynomial of degree (at most) $n+31$, with term $x^{n+32-j}$ present (resp. absent) when the $j$<sup>th</sup> bit in the result of the previous step is *one* (resp. *zero*), for $j$ with $0<j\le n+32$.
5. Compute the remainder of the polynomial division of that polynomial by the binary polynomial $x^{32}+x^{26}+x^{23}+x^{22}+x^{16}+x^{12}+x^{11}+x^{10}+x^8+x^7+x^5+x^4+x^2+x+1$, forming a binary polynomial of degree (at most) $31$.
6. Form the $32$-bit sequence with the $j$<sup>th</sup> bit *one* (resp. *zero*) when the term $x^{32-j}$ is present (resp. absent) in that polynomial, for $j$ with $0<j\le 32$.
7. Append that $32$-bit sequence to the **ORIGINAL** message (if it is to be converted to bytes: the first bit of that sequence shall be the low-order bit of the first byte unless otherwise specified).

Note: Inserting $32$ bits at step 2 allows a receiver to process bits of the message and $32$-bit sequence uniformly as they are being received, without knowing the frontier between the message and the final 32-bit sequence until after the end of that sequence. Step 3 makes it likely that suppression of bits in the message is detected including for *zero* bits at the beginning of the message.

Note: In term of binary polynomials (according to the conventions in steps 4 and 6), the combination of steps 2 and 3 changes $M(x)$ to $M(x)\cdot x^{32}+\displaystyle\sum_{i=n}^{n+31}{x^i}+\sum_{i=0}^{31}{x^i}$.

Note: Steps 4, 5 and 6 can be replaced by:

- repeat until the sequence has exactly 32 bits:

  - if the first bit is *one*:

    - complement the 7<sup>th</sup>, 10<sup>th</sup>, 11<sup>th</sup>, 17<sup>th</sup>, 21<sup>th</sup>, 22<sup>th</sup>, 23<sup>th</sup>, 25<sup>th</sup>, 26<sup>th</sup>, 28<sup>th</sup>, 29<sup>th</sup>, 31<sup>th</sup>, 32<sup>th</sup> and 33<sup>th</sup> bit.
  - remove the first bit.